# Which request culture provider is better option

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, localization, internationalization

I am working on localization in .NET Core Web API and stuck at choosing request culture provider option.

From the documentation, Microsoft provides three default culture providers that are automatically configured.

```
QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
CookieRequestCultureProvider
AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider
```

Apart from the above three, we can create a custom culture provider also, but my question is, which option is more secure and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on your app architecture, personally I prefer *custom made* route value request culture provider.

it will give you a clean urls e.g.:

> http://www.example.com/en-US/

here how you do create it:

First create a global route model convention for culture parameter:

```cs
public class CultureTemplateRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
            for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                var selector = model.Selectors[i];
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = -1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(
                      "{culture?}",
                      selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

then add it to razor pages options:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(o => {
            o.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplateRouteModelConvention());
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        });
```

then create RouteValueRequestCultureProvider :

```cs
public class RouteValueRequestCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo[] _cultures;

        public RouteValueRequestCultureProvider(CultureInfo[] cultures)
        {
            _cultures = cultures;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get {culture} route value from path string, 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
        /// <returns>ProviderCultureResult depends on path {culture} route parameter, or default culture</returns>
        public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var defaultCulture = "en";

            var path = httpContext.Request.Path;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultCulture));
            }

            var routeValues = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');
            if (routeValues.Count() <= 1)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultCulture));
            }

            if (!_cultures.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == routeValues[1].ToLower()))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultCulture));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(routeValues[1]));
        }
    }
```

Then add it to the culture providers list :

```cs
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(ops =>
            {
                ops.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                ops.SupportedCultures = mySupportedCultures;
                ops.SupportedUICultures = mySupportedUICultures;

                // add RouteValueRequestCultureProvider to the beginning of the providers list. 
                ops.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, 
                    new RouteValueRequestCultureProvider(cultures));
            });
```